Is the image of a degenerate simplex by a simplicial map a degenerate simplex? (Kerodon Remark 1.1.2.5)
Let $f:S_\bullet \rightarrow T_\bullet$ be a map of simplicial sets.

If $\sigma$ is a degenerate n-simplex of $S_\bullet$, then $f(\sigma)$ is a degenerate n-simplex of $T_\bullet$.
The converse holds if $f$ is a monomorphism of simplicial sets.

I know the question is stupid but I'm new to the topic and I have no one to discuss it with..
I follow Kerodon. This particular problem is the Remark 1.1.2.5
My solution
To distinguish the degeneracy operators of $T_\bullet$ and $S_\bullet$ I use the following convention:

$S^n_i : S_n \rightarrow S_{n+1}$ is the $i$-th degeneracy operator of $S_\bullet$
$T^n_i : T_n \rightarrow T_{n+1}$ is the $i$-th degeneracy operator of $ST_\bullet$

$1.$ If $\sigma$ is a degenerate n-simplex of $S_\bullet$ then exist $i \in [n-1]$ s.t. $\sigma \in Im S^{n-1}_i$. So there is $\alpha \in S_{n-1}$ s.t. $S^{n-1}_i(\alpha) = \sigma$. So we have
\begin{equation}
f_n(\sigma) = f_n(S^{n-1}_i(\alpha)) \overset{\ast}{=} T^{n-1}_i(f_{n-1}(\alpha))
\end{equation}
then $f_n(\sigma) \in Im T^{n-1}_i$. So $f_n(\sigma)$ is a degenerate simplex in $T_\bullet$.
$\ast$ is the naturality of $f$.
$2.$ For this question i have a partial (maybe incorrect) solution. If $f_n(\sigma)$ is a degenerate n-simplex of $T_\bullet$ then exist $i \in [n-1]$ s.t. $\sigma \in Im T^{n-1}_i$. So there is $\alpha \in T_{n-1}$ s.t. $T^{n-1}_i(\alpha) = f_n(\sigma)$.
Claim: $\alpha \in Im f_{n-1}$
By means of the claim exist $\beta \in S_{n-1}$ s.t. $f_{n-1}(\beta) = \alpha$. So we have
\begin{equation}
f_n(S^{n-1}_i(\beta)) \overset{\ast}{=} T^{n-1}_i(f_{n-1}(\beta)) = T^{n-1}_i(\alpha) = f_n (\sigma)
\end{equation}
Using that $f$ is mono we obtain $S^{n-1}_i(\beta) = \sigma$. Then $\sigma$ is a degenerate simplex in $S_\bullet$.
Now I don't know how to prove the claim. If you have ideas on how to test or alternative solutions, please feel free to suggest them.
P.S. this is my first post so if you have any suggestions to improve it please let me know.

Your proof of 1 is correct.
For 2, here's a hint on how to prove your claim: show that for every degeneracy map $s : [n+1] \to [n]$ in the simplex category, there's a map $d : [n] \to [n+1]$ such that $s \circ d = \mathrm{id}_{[n]}$: intuitively, every degeneracy of a simplex $\alpha$ has $\alpha$ as one of its faces.

Thank you very much for your suggestion. To avoid misunderstandings with my notation instead of d I will write $\delta^i_n$. I found a map $d^i_n: [n] \rightarrow [n+1]$ s.t. $\delta^i_n \circ d^i_n = id_{[n]}$. This map associates $j$ to $j$ if $j \leq i$ otherwise $j + 1$. I rewrote the relation applying simplial sets to it. However, I did not understand what connection it has with showing that $\alpha$ belongs to the image of $f_{n-1}$. Could you explain to me how they are connected? Thanks again.

We now have $\alpha = d^i_{n-1}(s^i_{n-1}(\alpha)) = d^i_{n-1}(f_n(\sigma)) = f_{n-1}(d^i_{n-1}(\sigma))$, where I reuse $d^i_n$ and $s^i_n$ for the corresponding maps of presheaves.

What a fool I am. Now everything is clear. Thanks again for helping me.
